# Need sql or stored procedure to get data according to flag?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle

**Ex- I have Table Name_Type as below -**

```
+--------------+----------+
| Name_Type_Id |  Code    |
+--------------+----------+
|            1 |   AN     |
|            2 |   BN     |
|            3 |   CN     |
|            4 |   DN     |
|            5 |   EN     |
|            6 |   FN     |
+--------------+----------+
```

**Second Table Table_A as below -**

```
+-------+---------+--------------+------------------+
|  T_ID | T_Value | Name_Type_Id | Name_Type_Value  |
+-------+---------+--------------+------------------+
|  T1   |  A      |            1 |               1  |
|  T1   |  B      |            3 |               0  |
|  T2   |  A      |            2 |               1  |
|  T2   |  B      |            5 |               1  |
|  T2   |  C      |            6 |               1  |
|  T3   |  A      |            1 |               0  |
|  T3   |  B      |            6 |               1  |
|  T4   |  A      |            1 |               0  |
|  T5   |  A      |            2 |               1  |
+-------+---------+--------------+------------------+
```

**Need result set as below -**

```
+-------+---------+------+------+-------+-----+
| T_ID  | T_Value | AN   |  BN  |   EN  |  FN |
+-------+---------+------+------+-------+-----+
|    T1 |  A      |  1   |   0  |   0   |   0 |
|    T1 |  B      |  0   |   0  |   0   |   0 |
|    T2 |  A      |  0   |   1  |   0   |   0 |
|    T2 |  B      |  0   |   0  |   1   |   0 |
|    T2 |  C      |  0   |   0  |   0   |   1 |
|    T3 |  A      |  0   |   0  |   0   |   0 |
|    T3 |  B      |  0   |   0  |   0   |   1 |
|    T4 |  A      |  0   |   0  |   0   |   0 |
|    T5 |  A      |  0   |   1  |   0   |   0 |
+-------+---------+------+------+-------+-----+
```

**Desc -** 
Here in Second table Table_A T_ID & T_Value is unique.
I need name_type_code as column name in result only for which value "1" is present in table_A.
Ex. Like for name_type_code "DN" there is no value for any T_ID 
Same for CN like we have value "0" so we don't want.

Comment: I can't figure out how you end up with that output based on the two input tables.  Can you explain how the codes (only 4 out of 6 of them) end up as column names?

Comment: And why the duplicate rows, isn’t the point of pivoting data like this to gather everything in one row?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson we have other column and value also that are unique like for T1 we two values A & B, I have not added here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I need distinct name_type_code as column name in result only for which value "1" is present in table_A. Ex. Like for name_type_code "DN" there is no value for any T_ID Same for "CN" like we have value "0" so we don't want.

Comment: Your output must match the input you have given because how can we help you with a correct query otherwise?

Comment: Delete this question, and post again, making sure to clearly explain your logic.  The best way to explain a SQL query is to show minimal input and the expected output.  You don't necessarily need a query/data set this complex to get help with how to approach your problem.

Comment: @AnshulDubey in future please use this as your format table.. https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/

Comment: @dwir182 i tried to edit and format my table with https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ but something gone wrong

Comment: Just add space to match your column with your data..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may prefer using `decode` as :

```
select a.t_id, a.T_Value,
       decode(n.code,'AN',a.value,0) as "AN",
       decode(n.code,'BN',a.value,0) as "BN",
       decode(n.code,'EN',a.value,0) as "EN",
       decode(n.code,'FN',a.value,0) as "FN"
  from Table_A a
  left join Name_Type n 
    on ( n.name_type_id = a.name_type_id )    
  group by a.t_id, a.T_Value, a.value, n.code  
  order by a.t_id, a.T_Value;

  T_ID  T_VALUE AN  BN  EN  FN
   T1       A   0   0   0   0
   T1       B   1   0   0   0
   T2       A   0   1   0   0
   T2       B   0   0   1   0
   T2       C   0   0   0   1
   T3       A   0   0   0   0
   T3       B   0   0   0   1
   T4       A   0   0   0   0
   T5       A   0   1   0   0
```

Comment: Is there option to remove hard code name_type like decode(n.code,'AN',a.value,0) as "AN", here stored procedure also will be good for me.

Comment: @AnshulDubey unfortunately, there's no.